# How to execute function on a certain URL

Tags: javascript, url

I've got a page at let's say http://localhost:1234
I've got some JS code let's say:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var k = 0; k < links.length; k++) {

    if (links[k].getAttribute('title') == null) {
        links[k].style.border = '5px dashed red'
    }
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var t = 0; t < images.length; t++) {

    if ((images[t].getAttribute('alt') == null) || (images[t].getAttribute('alt') == '')) {
        images[t].style.border = '5px dashed red'
    }
}
```

What I wanna achieve is executing the code above only if I visit http://localhost:1234?init but still for the index page.
Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
In your js code check for window.location.href or document.URL if it matches with http://localhost:1234?init then you can call your function.

For Example:

if(window.location.href == 'http://localhost:1234?init') {functionCall();}
```